# Foundation: vertical sub-nav

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Is it possible to make a vertical sub-nav? In the doc page there's only the horizontal one and I can't find out how to display the elements vertically

EDIT: here is the link to foundation docs: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/subnav.html

And this is the original css (Extracted from foundation.css):

```
.sub-nav 
{
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: -0.25rem 0 1.125rem;
    padding-top: 0.25rem;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: -0.75rem; 
}

.sub-nav dt 
{
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.sub-nav dt,
.sub-nav dd,
.sub-nav li 
{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    color: #999999; 
}

.sub-nav dt a,
.sub-nav dd a,
.sub-nav li a 
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
    padding: 0.1875rem 1rem; 
}

.sub-nav dt a:hover,
.sub-nav dd a:hover,
.sub-nav li a:hover 
{
    color: #737373; 
}

.sub-nav dt.active a,
.sub-nav dd.active a,
.sub-nav li.active a 
{
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #008cba;
    padding: 0.1875rem 1rem;
    cursor: default;
    color: white; 
}

.sub-nav dt.active a:hover,
.sub-nav dd.active a:hover,
.sub-nav li.active a:hover 
{
    background: #0078a0; 
}
```

Comment: No code, no example, no link to the documentation. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to modify the original foundation css and to override the sub-nav class in my css file, but so far I haven't been able to achieve my goal

Comment: So show us what you have so far and we can point you in the right direction. Make a JSfiddle.net Demo

Answer (score 0):

Assigning 'vertical' class is assigned in the html like so:

```
<ul class="vertical menu">
    <li><a href="oranges.html">Oranges</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Limes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lemons</a></li>
</ul>
```

Just using vertical defaults to small. For instance `<ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu"  ... >` will be vertical for small width and horizontal for medium width. I hope this helps.